# How do I consume local node / npm module in deno?

Tags: node.js, deno

I've a monorepo project with Nextjs and supabase. I want to build a shared module for type and schema definations and consume in both Nextjs and supabase codebase. I can easily use local module in node projects like Nextjs using `npm install ../lib` and `import { X } from "myApp-lib"` provided that `lib/package.json` declares `"name": "myApp-lib"`.

How do I consume local node module in `deno` in similar fashion?

##### Directory Structure

```
myApp/
  client/
   src/
     components/
       - contact.tsx # schema consumer

  supabase/
    functions/
      email_new_query/
        - index.ts # Deno module, schema consumer - how to?

  lib/
    dist/
      index.js # schema provider / exporter
      index.d.ts # types definations
```

Comment: See the GitHub issue at [denoland/deno#18474](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/18474)

Answer (score 0):

First. use `esbuild` or `webpack` to bundle your Node.js code into a single JavaScript file that uses ES modules.

```
esbuild index.js --bundle --outfile=dist/bundle.js --format=esm
```

Then, you would have to host modules somewhere to use them in Deno. If using some live server, you can provide a URL from which Deno can import the module.

```
import { X } from "http://localhost:8000/path/to/your/bundle.js";
```

Also you can host it somewhere else and then use in deno:

```
import { X } from "https://yourhost.com/path/to/your/bundle.js";
```